# State do not update onClick in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, e-commerce

Yahya here

I am building Ecommerce App in react with the help of Strapi

This is my code:

```
// var is used because I want to use state in different functions

var [ functionIsRunning , setFunctionIsRunning] = useState(false);


const handleFavourite = () => {

    setFunctionIsRunning(true);
}

const navigateToSinglePage = () => {

    if(functionIsRunning=== false)

    {
        navigate("/product/" + id)
    }
}


return (
    <div className="product-card" onClick={navigateToSinglePage}>
        <div className="thumnail">
            <img src={process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_URL + data?.img?.data[0]?.attributes.url} alt="" />
            <div className="heart" onClick={handleFavourite}>
            <  AiOutlineHeart/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="product-details">
            <span className="Name">{data?.Title}</span>
            <span className="price">Rs {data?.Price}</span>                
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

The states always remains false

I want add product in favourite without redirecting to Single Product page

If someone has another way to execute this process you can narrate

REGARDS!

Comment: _"var is used because I want to use state in different functions"_: `const` or `let` would be fine as the state is scoped to the component function in which those function expressions sit. But on your problem: how are you checking that the state is still false? Are you using a `useEffect` to check the state after its been changed?

Comment: The logic of this component doesn't make sense to me.  Does `navigate` direct the user somewhere else?  What is this state update even trying to accomplish?  You're queueing a state update, but then *immediately* navigating away.  If that navigation causes the component to unload, its state is lost anyway.  Since this navigation occurs in a click handler, where do you ever even plan to *use* this state value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use useEffect hooks. Create a handle click function like this:

```
handleClick = () => {
 #set your state variable to a new value here 
}
```

Then use a use effect hook to perform an action when the state is changed like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  #navigate user to a different page here
}, [<insert state variable to execute on here>]);
```

The reason for this is that react components are meant to be pure, meaning they always have the same output for the same input. So any "side effects" that you want to occur on the change of a state, must occur inside a use effect hook, which will execute everytime the state is changed.